# Axis with array values, highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, highcharts

I have in my script:

```
var categoria = new Array();
        for (var i=0;i<3;++i)
        {
               (function(j) {
                         categoria[j] = "data number"+j;
                         return j;
               })(i);
        }
$(".pastel").highcharts({
.
.
.
xAxis: {
       categories[categoria]
       },
.
.
.
});
```

if I exported with [CSV plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export-CSV) shows me this:

> (shows data improperly using array "categoria")

[image: Using array in xAxis]

aXis format should be as follows(correctly):

```
$(".pastel").highcharts({
.
.
.
xAxis: {
       categories["data number 0","data number 1","data number 2"] /* with the array "categoria" is expected to get this format, the correct way. */
       },
.
.
.
});
```

if I exported with [CSV plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export-CSV) shows me this:

> (shows data appropriately, I need to do this but with the array "categoria")

[image]

> How I can do to make the array using "categoria" displays data as in the image 2?
>   is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
.
xAxis: {
   categories:categoria
   },
.
.
```